# How to test facebook application via localhost?

Tags: facebook

I am researching how to build apps in `facebook.` I downloaded a standard application facebook provides called `"friendsmash"`.

The link I use as canvas URL is: `localhost:8080/friendsmash_social/`

When i try to load the facebook application it won't display anything.
How can i test the application without publishing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the Canvas url as: `http://localhost:8080/friendsmash_social/`.

You can not see this in the localhost, but you can test your application by running `http://localhost:8080/friendsmash_social/` in your browser

Comment: Of course you can. When you are ready with the app just change the canvas url and check if everything is fine.

Comment: but then i would need a Secure Canvas URL which i do not have is there a way arround?

Comment: No. No way around, without purchasing SSL certification you can deploy your app on facebook. But if your app is in development, you can deploy (giving Secure canvas the same url) but that wont be available for the public